# Selecting all uppercased-value rows of a table in SQL Navigator

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with an email address column. Some email addresses in the table contain uppercase letters. I would like to fetch all the rows with uppercase emails (in order to set them to lowercase). How do I select all the rows where the email address contains uppercase letters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe Oracle is [case sensitive by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7425931/163495)?  If so, then this should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE LOWER(email) <> email
```

If this works then you can simply update them with

```
UPDATE table_name
SET email = LOWER(email)
WHERE LOWER(email) <> email
```

Comment: Damn, you were a minute faster :P

Comment: @d33tah - a minute is too long time between answers here in SO :P