# Is oracle case sensitive in ddl statements

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl, ora-00904

Following fails to execute

```
create table product_instance (
  "ID" number(19,0),
  constraint pro_instance_pk primary key ("id")
)
```

giving the output

```
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "id": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

However the changing "id" to "ID" works fine

```
create table product_instance (
  "ID" number(19,0),
  constraint pro_instance_pk primary key ("ID")
)
```

Following also works fine

```
create table product_instance (
  ID number(19,0),
  constraint pro_instance_pk primary key (id)
)
```

Appreciate if someone could answer the effect of specifying "ID" instead of just id in the DDL statements. Is oracle case sensitive or insensitive

Answer (score 1):

When you use quotes, it makes the column name case sensitive.  See this [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425153/reason-why-oracle-is-case-sensitive)

Comment: This behaviour is especially nasty when people use reserved words as names for columns or tables... Column-name "exclusive" will not match "EXCLUSIVE", e.g. ... :P

Answer (score -1):

Oracle is insensitive in DDL statements. for creating a table we cannot use field name in the ("") double quotes.

```
 sql>create table product_instance (
     "ID" number(19,0)***,***
      constraint pro_instance_pk primary key ("ID")
      )
```

This code doesn't execute on the sql promt.
 and to apply constraints on the table there should not be semicolon in between datatype and constraint.

Comment: Using double-quotes in DDL *makes* Oracle case sensitive.  The posted script does run, because that's a comma not a semi-colon; the comma is the correct syntax when defining a table level cronstraint.