# "Relation not found" error when using Django without syncdb

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a small Django project with simple models. However, instead of creating my database via `python manage.py syncdb` I decided to create it manually and map the tables via `Meta`, as shown below

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
            managed = False                                                   
            db_table = 'ITEM'
```

but this doesn't work. When I start the development server and run the main view, Django throws an error saying that the relation named `ITEM` doesn't exist in the database, when in fact it does exist.

I have done some research but couldn't find anyone with such a problem. Is there a way I can get it working?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yep. This is the weird thing.

Comment: Could it be a capitalization issue?  Postgres converts table names to lowercase unless the queries have quotes around them: http://binodsblog.blogspot.com/2011/02/postgresql-is-case-sensitive.html

Comment: @CantucciHQ WOW what a surprise, I'd never suspect that could be the problem. Please answer the question so I can accept it :D

Comment: @Mauren That's SQL standard behaviour, btw, though the SQL spec says names should be _upper_-cased if not quoted.

Comment: @CraigRinger I'm more of an ORM person, since I spent nearly 4 years of my life working with JPA and Oracle database. I've never faced such a problem while using Oracle (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425153/reason-why-oracle-is-case-sensitive)), so this was a big surprise to me that Postgres does make case-sensitive identifier matching.

Comment: @Mauren Oracle isn't known for following the spec closely ;-) . I'm not a fan of this particular SQL-spec behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres converts table names to lowercase letters unless the queries have quotes around them. See for example:

http://binodsblog.blogspot.com/2011/02/postgresql-is-case-sensitive.html

Normally that detail is abstracted away by the ORM, but if you don't use syncdb, you have to manage it.

Answer (score 2):

The db_table name should be in lowercase:

```
db_table = 'item'
```