# How to make oracle table names case insensitive?

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

I have a query like this: `$this->db->select("SELECT * FROM foo");`
Now if the table name is `Foo`, and I execute this script on MySQL istance all working good (table name on MySQL is even with lowercase letters, so: foo. Buy if I execute this on Oracle that have the table name as Foo. I'll get:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'test_db.foo' doesn't exist

'Cause on Oracle istance is called Foo not foo. Some idea to fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425153/reason-why-oracle-is-case-sensitive says that table names are case-insensitive unless you put them in quotes.

Comment: This is strange, I don't surround the table name in the quote.

Comment: Did you use quotes when creating the table?

Comment: Not so strange, as all unquoted names are changed to same case (all uppercase by default) on input . So if your table name is not _FOO_, you will experience this error.

Comment: This also happean if I pass FOO in my query. And I create the table without any quotes.

Comment: Do a describe on the table, please.

Comment: I assume the problem is caused by missing privileges rather than capitalization of tables names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[TL;DR] The simplest thing to do is to never use double quotes around object names and just let oracle manage the case-sensitivity in its default manner.**

Oracle databases are, by default, case sensitive; however, they will also, by default, convert everything to upper-case so that the case sensitivity is abstracted from you, the user.

```
CREATE TABLE tEsT ( column_name NUMBER );
```

Then:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Test;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TEST;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tEsT;
```

Will all give the same output and:

```
SELECT * FROM USER_TABLES;
```

Outputs:

```
TABLE_NAME
----------
TEST
```

(Note the table name is in upper case).

If you use double quotes then oracle will respect your use of case in the table name:

```
CREATE TABLE "tEsT" ( column_name NUMBER );
```

and:

```
SELECT * FROM USER_TABLES;
```

Outputs:

```
TABLE_NAME
----------
TEST 
tEsT
```

(Note: there are now two tables named `TEST` and `tEsT` and oracle has respected the case sensitivity of the second one - the one created with quotes).

(Also note: `SELECT * FROM tEsT` will select from the first table, which has been converted to upper-case, but `SELECT * FROM "tEsT"` is required to select from the second even though the queries are identical apart form the quotes).

Comment: Nope, still the same error. I have created the table with no quote around then name. Anyway when I execute show create table table name I noticed a backtick around the table name