# Oracle TYPE declaration throwing error PLS-00201 - identifier must be declared

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, types

I created a Object Type successfully using below command:

```
create or replace 
TYPE  "SharedAccountRecType" AS object(
 account_id NUMBER(11),
 share_by_id NUMBER(11),
 share_to_id NUMBER(11)
);
```

Then I tried to create another Type as a table of above successfully created Object Type. Below command is throwing error:

```
create or replace 
TYPE "SharedAccountRecTypeCollection" 
as table of SharedAccountRecType
```

Error:  PLS-00201: identifier 'SHAREDACCOUNTRECTYPE' must be declared.

Both above commands were executed using same Oracle user, one after the other. Please help.

Comment: Try `create or replace 
TYPE "SharedAccountRecTypeCollection" 
as table of "SharedAccountRecType"`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35556194/1509264 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36559222/how-to-make-oracle-table-names-case-insensitive/36560361#36560361 - you are enforcing case sensitivity by using double quotes and lower case characters in the identifier - you need to continue using double quotes and the same case everywhere you use that identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use double quotes, Oracle will create a type with the exact name you typed, **case sensitive**.
For example:

```
SQL> create or replace
  2  TYPE  "SharedAccountRecType" AS object(
  3   account_id NUMBER(11),
  4   share_by_id NUMBER(11),
  5   share_to_id NUMBER(11)
  6  );
  7  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace
  2  TYPE  SharedAccountRecType AS object(
  3   account_id NUMBER(11),
  4   share_by_id NUMBER(11),
  5   share_to_id NUMBER(11)
  6  );
  7  /

Type created.

SQL> select type_name
  2  from user_types
  3  where upper(type_name) = 'SHAREDACCOUNTRECTYPE';

TYPE_NAME
------------------------------
SHAREDACCOUNTRECTYPE
SharedAccountRecType

SQL>
```

Given this, you may want to remove the double quotes from the creation of `SharedAccountRecType`:

```
create or replace  TYPE  SharedAccountRecType AS object ...
create or replace ... as table of SharedAccountRecType
```

or add them in the creation of the table type, depending whether you want case sensitive names or not

```
create or replace  TYPE  "SharedAccountRecType" AS object ...
create or replace ... as table of "SharedAccountRecType"
```

Comment: Thanks @Aleksej, the issue was that I was using double quotes while creating the object "SharedAccountRecType", but I wasn't using the double quotes which creating the table of type SharedAccountRecType. After reading your answer I tried Quotes everywhere and it just worked. Thanks a ton. I wasted 3 hours last night trying to understand what went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It is happened because you use "" in the name of type.

In Oracle names "SharedAccountRecType" and SharedAccountRecType are different.

Don't use name in "", because Oracle threat names in "" as case-sensitive, but name without "" as case-unsensitive uppercase.

Comment: Thanks @Vladimir. Great suggestion.

Comment: Quick Answer!!. Saved my time too