# Retrieve column name through db link in Oracle 11g

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, dblink

I want to retrieve column names from a table through a db link but I'm not able to do it...

Although this query is working

```sql
SELECT *
FROM myTableName@myDbLink;
```

the following one is not:

```sql
SELECT column_name
FROM all_tab_columns@myDbLink
WHERE table_name = 'myTableName'
```

What's the correct way of retrieving the column names?

Answer (score 4):

CaSE mATterS.

In Oracle, table names are - by default - in UPPERCASE, so - try with

```
SELECT column_name
FROM all_tab_columns@myDbLink
WHERE table_name = 'MYTABLENAME'
```

Comment: if myTableName in the select works, why should 'MYTABLENAME' works?

Comment: @JaviOverflow : Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425153/reason-why-oracle-is-case-sensitive

Comment: That's really interesting! I didn't know that. However, when I use "myTableName" in my select query, it's still working, so I guess I'm using the same-case-sensitive name.

Comment: Mixed case is *evil*, avoid creating Oracle objects using mixed case. If you want to do that, you'll have to use double quotes. And if you do that, you'll have to use double quotes everywhere, always, whenever you reference that object, and *never* fail letter case.