# Insert JSON data into Oracle using Python

Tags: python, sql, oracle

everybody. I'm having problems working with json files. I have such a list of Json data , how can I insert this data to a table? 
Python code:

```
with open('object.json') as f:
    json_obj = json.load(f)
print(json_obj)

for i in enumerate(json_obj):
    id = validate_string(item.get("id", None))
    LAST_NAME = validate_string(item.get("LAST_NAME", None))
    FIRST_NAME = validate_string(item.get("FIRST_NAME", None))
cursor.execute("insert into EMPLOYEES (id,LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME) VALUES (:1,:2,:3)", (id,LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME))
conn.close
```

JSON some dates in the (object.json) file:

```
[{"ID": 1, "LAST_NAME": "Alex", "FIRST_NAME": "Pip"}, 
{"ID": 2, "LAST_NAME": "John", "FIRST_NAME": "Alan"},
{"ID": 3, "LAST_NAME": "Dehan", "FIRST_NAME": "Luck"},
{"ID": 4, "LAST_NAME": "Nick", "FIRST_NAME": "Adem"},
{"ID": 5, "LAST_NAME": "Aspen", "FIRST_NAME": "Turit"}]
```

> DatabaseError: ORA-00904: "ID": invalid identifier

Comment: Once you've resolved the error (see the answer already proposed), then you should look at using `executemany()` to improve performance.  See the [cx_Oracle documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html).

Answer (score 2):

ORA-904 is "invalid identifier".

- Are you sure the column id exists ?
- Could it be you created the employee table with case sensititive column names, I see that in your insert statement you have "id" in lower case and "LAST_NAME" in upper case. If your column names are case sensitive you have to surround them with double quotes. Example:

```
create table test ("id" NUMBER, "Name" VARCHAR2(100));
INSERT INTO test (id, name) VALUES (1,'KOEN'); 
> gives ORA-00904: "NAME": invalid identifier 
INSERT INTO test ("id", "Name") VALUES (1,'KOEN');
1 row(s) inserted.
```

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425153/reason-why-oracle-is-case-sensitive)